# C++ Cin not executing properly

Tags: c++

I am having problems getting "cin >> calories" to execute properly. The code automatically sets calories = to -279846518796 and sometimes other numbers ( usually a big negative number like before). Thus making the end results a mess. Even if I set "calories" as an int I get the same error.

```
#include <iostream>

int main( ) 
{
int height, weight, age, edible_newfoods;
double bmr, calories;
char gender, activity_level, newfood;

//Take user inputs.
cout << "Please provide your information." << endl;
cout << "male or female (m or f): ";
cin >> gender;
cout << "age in years: ";
cin >> age;
cout << "weight in pounds: ";
cin >> weight;
cout << "height in inches: ";
cin >> height;

//Ask the user how active they are, to get an input between four choices
cout << endl << "How active are you?" << endl; 
cout << "   s - sedentary" << endl;
cout << "   c - casual exerciser--exercise ocasionally" << endl;
cout << "   a - active exerciser--exercise 3-4 days a week" << endl;
cout << "   d - devoted exerciser--exercise everyday" << endl;

//Take users activity level as a char
cout << "Enter the level of association with your activity level: ";
cin >> activity_level;

//Adding more food
cout << endl << "What type of food do you want to eat?" << endl;

cout << "Please use _ between words to create a single word. ";
cin >> newfood;

cout << "How many calories per item? ";
//This is where the cin automatically makes calories a giant negative number.
// causing the final output of results to be a mess.
cin >> calories;

//Calculations - Adjusting BMR to accommodate for activity level
switch (activity_level)
{
    case 's':
    case 'S': activity_level = 0.95; break;
    case 'c':
    case 'C': activity_level = 1.30; break;
    case 'a': 
    case 'A': activity_level = 1.40; break;
    case 'd':
    case 'D': activity_level = 1.50; break;
} 

if (age <= 65 && (gender == 'm' || gender == 'M')) {
    bmr = 1.375 * ((66 + 6.3 * weight) + (12.9 * height) - (6.8 * age));
}
else {
    bmr = 1.375 * ((655 + 4.3 * weight) + (4.7 * height) - (4.7 * age));
}

bmr = bmr * activity_level;

edible_newfoods = bmr / calories;

cout.setf(ios::fixed);
cout.setf(ios::showpoint);
cout.precision(0);

//output the results to user.
cout << endl << "The BMR for a " << weight << " pound " << gender << " who is " << age << " years    old is " << bmr
<< " calories number of " << newfood << " eaten = " << edible_newfoods;
}
```

Please be kind, I am new to stackoverflow, and coding. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You never checked the input operations for success.

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info (e.g. `g++ -Wall -g`). Then **use the debugger** (e.g. `gdb`)

Comment: Enable your compiler warnings and pay attention to them.

Comment: Please update your question to show your *entire* program. What you've posted will not compile. It's missing `#include <iostream>` and the closing `}`, among other things. Small details like this matter.

Answer (score 1):

`activity_level` is of type `char`, assigning `double` to it does not look correct:

```
char gender, activity_level, newfood;
...
activity_level = 0.95;
```

While it is still a valid language construction, it results in truncating of floating part and assigning `0` to `activity_level`. See comment of **@KeithThompson**.

It seems that two different variables are required,

- one (`char`) to be keep the input and be used in the `switch`, and
- another one (`double`) as the factor for `bmr = bmr * activity_level;`

Comment: That will set `activity_level` to `'\0'` (the `double` to integer conversion truncates). It's not wrong as far as the language is concerned, but it's certainly not what was intended.

Comment: I believe that's what I said.

Answer (score 0):

The problems start here:

```
cout << "Enter the level of association with your activity level: ";
cin >> activity_level;
```

`activity_level` has type `char`. When you do `cin >>` a char, then leading whitespace is not skipped. So this line picks up the Enter key that you pressed after the previous numeric input.  You should have noticed that the program never waited for you to enter anything here, and went straight on to displaying "Enter the level of association with your activity level".

The next problem is with the next input:

```
cout << "Please use _ between words to create a single word. ";
cin >> newfood;
```

`newfood` has type `char`. That means **a single character**. It can't hold any words (except "a" or "I").

To fix both of these problems , use `std::string` instead of `char`, for all three of those chars. Further, instead of using `cin >> newfood` which only gets a single word,`getline(cin, newfood);` which gets the whole line (and consumes the newline). Use this technique for `activity_level` and `gender` too.

The next problem is at:

```
switch (activity_level)
{
    case 's':
    case 'S': activity_level = 0.95;
```

You are trying to store `0.95` in a `char` which won't work. Use a new variable here, e.g. `double activity_factor`. Make sure to have a default value set, or a `default` case. Otherwise you will get garbage if the person didn't enter an expected character.

Finally , to prevent garbage output when there was invalid input, you can add the following before your final output:

```
if ( !cin )
{
    cerr << "Invalid input entered.\n";
    return 0;
}
```

or something similar. Then at least you get something sensible. To give more targeted error messages, perform this check after every input.